# Is possible to query data from track views?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

On Marketing Cloud, I am using the javascript tracking code to see how many and how has accessed my webpage. 
I can see the report at Web & Mobile Analytics tab.

Is possible to access this data from SQL queries to make a segmentation? If yes, how can I do it? (if possible, show some query examples).

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a catalog and then use this page ['Personalization Builder Integration with Contact Builder'](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_integration_with_contact_builder.htm&type=5) to push data to the igo_views DE.  WAMA does allow you to [export data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_export_data_from_wama.htm&type=5) to a DE for known visitors but you can't automate it

Comment: Can I push the data of which pages the visitor visited? (All my site is with tags)
Do I have to export a data as you said for this?